# Save image from RDD Apache Spark system

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to retrieve the images that I have stored on my RDD system after I map them.

I created a simple Spark Session on my `main.py` file which calls the function preprocess_spark that returns an array of tuples named `samples`. These tuples are in the `(slide_num, image)` format. Image is an `np.array` that will be converted to an image in the `save_jpeg_help` function.

When I open the Apache Spark WEB UI I see that it has a job corresponding to the line:

```
rdd.foreach(lambda sample_element: save_nonlabelled_sample_2_jpeg(sample_element, save_dir))
```

but when it finishes nothing is ever saved on my `save_dir` directory.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Kind regards

**main.py**

```
spark = (SparkSession.builder
     .appName("Oncofinder -- Preprocessing")
     .getOrCreate())

samples = preprocess_spark(spark, [1])

if save_jpegs: #SET TO TRUE
    save_rdd_2_jpeg(samples, './data/images')


def save_rdd_2_jpeg(rdd, save_dir):
    rdd.foreach(lambda sample_element: save_nonlabelled_sample_2_jpeg(sample_element, save_dir))


def save_nonlabelled_sample_2_jpeg(sample, save_dir):
    slide_num, img_value = sample
    filename = '{slide_num}_{hash}.jpeg'.format(
        slide_num=slide_num, hash=np.random.randint(1e4))
    filepath = os.path.join(save_dir, filename)
    save_jpeg_help(img_value, filepath)

def save_jpeg_help(img_value, filepath):
    dir = os.path.dirname(filepath)
    os.makedirs(dir, exist_ok=True)
    img = Image.fromarray(img_value.astype(np.uint8), 'RGB')
    img.save(filepath)


def preprocess_spark(spark, slide_nums, folder="data", training=False, tile_size=1024, overlap=0,
               tissue_threshold=0.9, sample_size=256, grayscale=False, normalize_stains=True,
               num_partitions=20000):

    slides = (spark.sparkContext
              .parallelize(slide_nums)
              .filter(lambda slide: open_slide(slide, folder, training) is not None))
    tile_indices = (slides.flatMap(
        lambda slide: process_slide(slide, folder, training, tile_size, overlap)))
    tile_indices = tile_indices.repartition(num_partitions)
    tile_indices.cache()

    tiles = tile_indices.map(lambda tile_index: process_tile_index(tile_index, folder, training))
    filtered_tiles = tiles.filter(lambda tile: keep_tile(tile, tile_size, tissue_threshold))
    samples = filtered_tiles.flatMap(lambda tile: process_tile(tile, sample_size, grayscale))
    if normalize_stains:
        samples = samples.map(lambda sample: normalize_staining(sample))

    return samples
```

**EDIT:** I'm using

`PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 spark-submit --master spark://127.0.1.1:7077 spark_preprocessing.py`

to run the application. It seems that after the `foreach` action, nothing else happens. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Are you running this on a single node or multiple nodes? Are you using a relative path or an absolute path?

Comment: Given that you're running this on multiple nodes, you definitely cannot just call `img.save(filepath)` and expect it to work like it would in normal Python execution. Lord only knows where on your cluster your image files are actually ending up. Instead, you'll have to `collect` the image arrays on the driver node and only then run `Image.fromarray` and `img.save` on those arrays.

Comment: I tried `rdd.collect().foreach(...)` instead of `rdd.foreach(...)` but I get `list object has not attribute foreach`

Comment: `rdd.collect()` will return a standard Python `list`. You would then have to iterate over the contents of that list and call your image saving function on each element. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the issue you're having if you `collect` all of your samples on to the driver node before you try to save them. If you redefine `save_rdd_2_jpeg` as:

```
def save_rdd_2_jpeg(rdd, save_dir):
    for sample in rdd.collect():
        save_nonlabelled_sample_2_jpeg(sample, save_dir)
```

then everything should work.